# firestore database with Vue: when I refresh the page I don't get the data on screen,

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I use Firestore with Vue and the problem is: I can't get the data from the database but when I change the `:key="Profiles['.key']"` to this `:key="Profiles"` then I see the data on my screen but when I refresh the page the data is gone it doesn't see it any more.

**This is the code:**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1 class="text-center mt-16">Admin</h1>
        <div v-for="Profiles in Profile" :key="Profiles" class="text-center mt-16">
            <p>{{Profiles.username}}</p>
            <p>{{Profiles.email}}</p>
            <p>{{Profiles.userId}}</p>
            <p>{{Profiles.role}}</p>
            <p>{{Profiles.haveAccess}}</p>
            <p>{{Profiles.createdAt}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
/*eslint-disable-line*/import { db } from '../../Database';
import firebase from 'firebase';
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            currentUser: firebase.auth().currentUser
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    },
    firestore: {
      Profile: db.collection('Profile')
    }
}
</script>
```

**Here is the data from the database.**
[image]

**But when I refresh the page I don't get the data anymore.**
[image]

Comment: Please have a look into this external [tutorial](https://medium.com/@akgarg007/vuejs-created-vs-mounted-life-cycle-hooks-74c522b9ceee). And also try the answer provided below from @Henrique and let me know if it works for you or not in order to investigate further.

Comment: I have solved it I add only a variable with a empty array: `Profile: []` and then it works. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the "Created" is only called during the creation of the page, for the request to be made every time it is accessed try to change the "Created" for "Mounted".

For more information search on Vue.js Life Cycle.